# java error in for loop condition evaluation: not a statement, illegal start of expression

Tags: java

I'm getting errors in the for loop condition statements...
Below is my code.

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class p3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // input
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    String result = "1";

    for (int j=1; j<num; j++) {
        if (checker(result+"1")) result = result+"1";
        else if (checker(result+"2")) result = result+"2";
        else result = result+"3";
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}

//checker function
boolean checker(String sr) {
    int n = sr.length();

    for (int m=1; m<=n/2; m++) {
        for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++) {
            if (sr.substring(i, i+m) == sr.substring(i+m, i+2m)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

and below is the error msg. Surely something is wrong with the loop condition in the checker() method, but I can't get it fixed.

```
p3.java:30: error: ';' expected
            for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++) {
                               ^
p3.java:30: error: not a statement
            for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++) {
                                ^
p3.java:30: error: ')' expected
            for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++) {
                                  ^
p3.java:30: error: ';' expected
            for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++) {
                                       ^
p3.java:31: error: ')' expected
                if (sr.substring(i, i+m) == sr.substring(i+m, i+2m)) {
                                                                 ^
p3.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
                if (sr.substring(i, i+m) == sr.substring(i+m, i+2m)) {
                                                                  ^
p3.java:31: error: ';' expected
                if (sr.substring(i, i+m) == sr.substring(i+m, i+2m)) {
                                                                   ^
7 errors
```

Comment: And for some reason I can't make this page to show my entire error message...

Comment: You do understand Java isn't like math? You need a * for multiplication. Also, `equals` for string comparison

Comment: Hint: write less code before running the compiler. And study java syntax rules. Or do you intend to come here for each and every compiler error you will run into? Side note: Please use braces for **any** block; even when it is just a one-line else or an if/else chain with one-liners! Finally: the name "checker" says nothing to the reader. You could rename it to *isResult()* for example.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid I am..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors

```
  for (int i=0; i<n-(2*m)+1; i++) { // use `*`
         // again use `*` also how to compare String - use equals
        if (sr.substring(i, i+m).equals (sr.substring(i+m, i+2 *m))) {  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also the method checker needs to be static as it is being called directly from `main`

```
 static boolean checker(String sr) {
```

**Multiply** use `*`

**String comparision** - use `equals`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are specifying the expression as a test condition in the concerned `for` loop is wrong. Instead of `for (int i=0; i<n-2m+1; i++)` I guess you wanted it to be `for (int i=0; i<(n-(2*m)+1); i++)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not use usual equations in your program

   for example: `n-2m+1` should be `n-2*m+1`
2. You cannot simply call `checker(result+"2")` from main method
   because main() method is static. Either create an object of `p3`
   class and call checker, or make `checker()` method also static.

**Final Code would be**

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class p3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        String result = "1";

        for (int j = 1; j < num; j++) {
            if (checker(result + "1")) result = result + "1";
            else if (checker(result + "2")) result = result + "2";
            else result = result + "3";
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //checker function
    static boolean checker(String sr) {
        int n = sr.length();

        for (int m = 1; m <= n / 2; m++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 2 * m + 1; i++) {
                if (sr.substring(i, i + m) == sr.substring(i + m, i + 2 * m)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about String comparison?

Comment: I think I've fixed that in my code... Though I haven't addressed it because this problem is the same as in point #1